# Unable to copy data to temporary table using select statement in sql - server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot-table, temp-tables

I am copying the data to temporary table using select statement which produces the result of pivoting.

My procedure is:

```
alter procedure proc11 AS

create Table #Temp (Software varchar(max), Ver varchar(max))

declare @cols varchar(max)
declare @colTabl varchar(max)
declare @alter varchar(max)

set @cols=STUFF((select distinct  ',[' + Ltrim(rtrim(YEAR(Dt))) +']' from temp FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');

set @colTabl=STUFF((select distinct  '[' + Ltrim(rtrim(YEAR(Dt))) +'] int,' from temp FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'');

set @colTabl= LEFT(@colTabl,len(@colTabl)-1);

set @alter = 'alter table #Temp add  '+ @colTabl;

exec(@alter)

EXEC('select * into #Temp from 
(select YEAR(Dt)[year],Software,Ver from temp)T
Pivot(count([year]) for [year] in ('+@cols+'))PVT')
```

But the statement `select * from #Temp` returns no record.

How do I copy these records.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EXEC('insert #Temp select * from 
(select YEAR(Dt)[year],Software,Ver from temp)T 
Pivot(count([year]) for [year] in ('+@cols+'))PVT order by Software')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because '#' temporary tables are kept just for the duration of current connection, and visible only in it's scope. Even if you create a temp table, open another tab in SSMS and try to use it, you you'll see "table does not exist" error.
What happens is, that your EXEC statement create the #Temp table, and when it finieshes, the table is immediately dropped. Not only that - #Temp table from CREATE statement, and #Temp from EXEC statement are in fact different tables! Try creating two #temp tables in different SSMS tabs and you'll see they're in fact not the same.

You could use global temp tables. Just change the name to ##Temp and it should work.
Run these two examples.

This won't work:

```
EXEC('select * into #Temp from (select ''something'' as x) x');
select * from #Temp
```

And this one will (when you run it second time you'll notice "table already exists" error:

```
EXEC('select * into ##Temp from (select ''something'' as x) x');
select * from ##Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply remove the `INSERT` from the dynamic portion:

```
INSERT INTO #temp
EXEC(select * from 
    (select YEAR(Dt)[year],Software,Ver from temp)T 
    Pivot(count([year]) for [year] in ('+@cols+'))PVT order by Software')
```